# Run Terraform as a Go Library?

Tags: go, terraform, terratest

I've been using Terratest to test all my go modules and absolutely love it as a means for running terraform and interacting with terraform infrastructure through the go programming language. However, terratest is designed to be integrated with the go test framework, not as a Go application of its own, which would be my goal.

Doing a quick search to find terraform go libraries I found Terranova does this, but is outdated. Is there a go library that someone has created currently that's similar to Terratest? Or is there a good way to run terraform as a go library instead of as a wrapper for the commands?

Answer (score 2):

There is a HashiCorp library for running Terraform from Go programs called [terraform-exec](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec).

However, this library is a wrapper for running Terraform CLI, because that is the only supported way to integrate programmatically with Terraform. Terraform CLI is an application, not a library.